# For a Django middleware class, how can process_request work just fine, but process_exception not be called?

Tags: django, middleware, django-middleware

I've created my own middleware class in Django that was working just fine until recently. The strange thing is that *process_request* still gets called just fine, but even when the response is 500 - internal server error, process_exception is not called at all. Why?

It makes no difference whether I declare my middleware class as the first or the last entry in the list of installed middleware in the settings file.

Comment: Can it be, that process_exception itself raises an exception?

Comment: Put `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` at the beginning of your `process_exception` method, then fire up runserver and cause a 500 error. If runserver drops into a pdb session, your method is definitely getting called. Then, step through to see what happens.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I want to add details to the exception email. I found a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678895/django-error-reporting-how-to-know-which-user-triggered-the-error. I implemented and the process_exception() doesn't seem to run. I added a process_request() method and appended the request.META['MYVAR'] = "funky" and that gets included in the emails, but I can't seem to get process_exception() to fire. I also have tried different locations (first and last) in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting.

Comment: I tried excluding middleware classes until I narrowed it down to the AuthenticationMiddle class. When that one is excluded, my process_exception() runs, but if it is enabled, mine does not run, the standard one does.

Comment: @Justin Poliey This question is almost a year old and I don't have quick access to the code that would let me verify solutions. Is it my responsibility to select an answer for the bounty to be awarded?

Answer (score 10):

The `process_exception` [only gets invoked when the view raises an `Exception`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py#L111). As it says in the comment:

> If the view raised an exception, run it through exception middleware,
> and if the exception middleware returns a response, use that.
> Otherwise, reraise the exception.

Exceptions raised by misconfiguration, importing error, `process_request` and `process_view` cannot be caught and feed to `process_exception` handlers.

To test whether your `process_exception` works, raise an Exception in the view after you ensure it works well.

There is not direct relationship between `process_request` and `process_exception`. They are handlers for different purposes and get invoked at different stages. Any Exception been raised after the `process_request` that executed successfully and before the view, will not be caught and processed by `process_exception` as said.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation for *process_exception*,

> process_exception(self, request, exception)
> takes an HttpRequest object, an Exception object raised by the view function as arguments and returns an HttpResponseobject as response. So, it will not be called when the code raises a 500 error (an HttpResponse object). The process_exception will be called only for uncaught exceptions in the views.

Comment: It couldn't have been formatted that badly. What is the source?