# A middleware with process exception never called

Tags: python, exception, django

I have this middelware which is suppose to catch 500/400 exceptions and deal with them. But it never gets called. I've put it in the beginning and end of the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` but it still doesn't run when an exception is raised:

**vertical/middleware.py:**

```
class HandleExceptionsMiddleware(object):
       def process_exception(self, request, exception):
             print >> sys.stderr, "exception has been raised"
             # Get the exception info now, in case another exception is thrown later.
             if isinstance(exception, http.Http404):
                   return self.handle_404(request, exception)
             else:
                   return self.handle_500(request, exception)
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       'vertical.middleware.HandleExceptionsMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 )
```

Comment: Two quick questions: If you would add an __init__() method, is that invoked? And: can you do a "from vertical.middleware import HandleExceptionsMiddleWare" from your (manage.py) shell?

Comment: This question is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466792/for-a-django-middleware-class-how-can-process-request-work-just-fine-but-proce

Answer (score 0):

> middleware are run in **reverse** order during the response phase, which
>   includes process_exception. If an exception middleware returns a
>   response, the middleware classes above that middleware will not be
>   called at all.

Comment: I have the same issue. The question mentions - I've put it in the beginning and end of the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES but it still doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Following checklist helped me with similar problem:

1. Check if middleware is properly created ([refer to middleware docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware))
2. Check python dotted path in `MIDDLEWARES` with middleware you are working on
3. Check if your middleware is at the bottom of `MIDDLEWARES`

If still not working, that means other middleware captures exception and returns response, or other middleware is calling your view out of order or way too soon.

4. Check if your other middlewares are returning `None` (explicitly or implicitly)
5. Check if your other middlewares are not directly calling `view_func` in `process_view`